# Get line from text file - php

Tags: php, arrays, function, file-io

So basically this is what I want to do:

I have a folder with 100 .txt files, which I listed like this:

```
$directory = 'files';
$phpfiles = scandir($directory);
foreach($phpfiles as $phpfile)
{
print_r ("<ul><a href=files/$phpfile>".basename($phpfile)."</a></ul><br/>");
}
```

Each text file contains around 20 lines with different variable names `(TEXT;1 TEXT;2 etc.)`. I want to be able get a separate input field for each line, in order to edit it, and then save the file. I have absolutely no idea how to get extract a single line from a .txt file, or if it's even possible with PHP. Java is also acceptable.

Basically, the lines in the text file looks like this:

```
TEXT;1;;34;0.0;22.0;105.0
TEXT;2;;34;0.0;22.0;23.0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of [`file()`][1] in PHP. This function reads your text file in an array line by line.

```
<?php
$arrbyline=file('yourfilename'));
```

So you can access each line by `$arrbyline[0],$arrbyline[1],...` so on
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Alternatively, you can loop and `explode()` too

```
foreach($arrbyline as $lines)
{
 .... // you can explode each element..
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Then how do I make each line editable through an input field?

Comment: Just add something like  `echo "<input type = 'text' value=".$lines.">";` inside your `foreach`